# Run Ruby on Rails on VPS BlueHost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vps, bluehost

I just upload all my Ruby on Rails into BlueHost VPS Server. I already setup the application and command "rails s" is working. But when I tried to access the application, I got 404 error.

I tried :

```
1. <ip_address>/APPNAME:3000
2. <ip_address>/APPNAME
```

Both are return 404. I already tried to followed BlueHost documentation, and I tried to asked support too, but they didn't help at all.

I had once deploy a Ruby on Rails application into BlueHost too, and when I try to access it with port, just like what I did, I can see the application, but not with this one.

Could somebody help me? Thank you.

Comment: If it's just a regular VPS, you should access if via `<ip_address>:3000` (no app name). Also, make sure Rails server is bound to `0.0.0.0`, not to `127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I did that too, but it doesn't work.